# Copy values to another dataframe from row based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

In my dataframe (df), I need to:

- For all rows where the value in 'Column A' == Yes
- The value in 'Column B' should be:

  - The value of 'Column E' in dataframe 'df2' of the row where 'df2' 'Column D' == 'df' 'Column C'

Currently I have this:

```
df.loc[df['Column A'] == 'Yes', 'Column B'] = df2.loc[(df2['Column D'] == df['Column C']), 'Column E']
```

However this results in:

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Example of my dataframes:

```
df:
Column A   Column B   Column C
Yes                   2554072
No                    2557766
No                    261191
Yes                   2600355
Yes                   2601388
...                   ...

df2:
Column D  Column E
2554072   8
2601388   4
2604142   6
...       

Required results:
df:
Column A   Column B   Column C
Yes        8          2554072
No                    2557766
No                    261191
Yes        NoMatch    2600355
Yes        4          2601388
...                   ...
```

I have tried to change the values in all of these columns to string and fill NaN values in Column C, however the ValueError is persistent. Any suggestions?

Comment: Provide minimal reproducible inputs of your dataframes, and the matching expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and mask with [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['Column B'] = (df['Column C']
                  .map(df2.set_index('Column D')['Column E'])
                  .where(df['Column A'].eq('Yes'))
                 )
```

Or, with [boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
m = df['Column A'].eq('Yes')
df.loc[m, 'Column B'] =  (df.loc[m, 'Column C']
                          .map(df2.set_index('Column D')['Column E'])
                         )
```

Example:

```
# df
  Column A Column C
0      Yes        A
1       No        B
2      Yes        C
3       No        D
4      Yes        E
5       No        F

# df2
  Column D  Column E
0        D         0
1        E         1
2        F         2
3        A         3
4        B         4
5        C         5

# Output
  Column A Column C  Column B
0      Yes        A       3.0
1       No        B       NaN
2      Yes        C       5.0
3       No        D       NaN
4      Yes        E       1.0
5       No        F       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also applicable:

```
output_df= pd.merge(df, df2,  left_on='Column C', right_on='Column D', how='left')

output_df['Column B'] = result_df.apply(lambda row: row['Column E'] if 
row['Column A'] == 'yes' else row['Column B'], axis=1)
```